# SSIS VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've created a SSIS package in SQL Server to export data from a ODBC source(QuickBase app). I've also scheduled it through a sql job agent in SQL Server and everything is working perfectly.

When there is some changes in source the job will fail.

I'm encountering an error VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA when I modify the column of source tables from which I'm exporting data.

After refresh metadata it was working but i want permanent solution for this error.

how can I refresh metadata automatically, please hep me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality provided by SSIS itself. The metadata is a design time function and hence static. You'll have to refresh and revalidate each time the underlying metadata changes. 
There are some custom components on codeplex which do the automatic metadata refresh. But the last time I saw one, it was able to do that only for file-system storage.

Just curious to know why do you need to frequently change the metadata? This error comes when an existing column is modified. If the database design is correct, then I would assume such changes will be minimal.

Comment: My source is Quickbase data and it will Change frequently because of user requirement is to add new column in source then my package give me this error

Comment: If the requirement is to add new columns to the source then the metadata error should not occur as long as you have not written something similar to "select *" retrieving all columns from the source. If you have specified the column names then metadata error will only occur if you change information about these columns. New columns will not cause an issue.

Comment: yes, in my source connection i have select table view and table view is like "select *"

Answer (score 1):

This is when -> You have column name mismatch between source and destination (Correct the name and it should work)
-> You added/ deleted column(s) in source and destination (refresh the metadata)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by opening the advanced editor for the source and change the setting "ValidateExternalMetadata" to FALSE